# Angular.js: How do I use ng-bind to display concat. elements of an array as a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and have a basic question about ng-bind that I couldn't find in the documentation. My scenario is based the shopping cart app in the O'Reily Angular.js book and I cannot seem to get ng-bind to work.

**Desired output:** I need to modify my controller function so I can show my updated $scope.items array elements in a 'Grand Total' span.

Here is the function:

```
 function CartController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {title: 'Software', quantity: 1, price: 1399.95},
      {title: 'Data Package (1TB)', quantity: 1, price: 719.95},
      {title: 'Consulting (per hr.)', quantity: 1, price: 75.00}
    ];

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    },

    $scope.reset = function(index) {
      $scope.items = [
      {title: 'Software', quantity: 0, price: 1399.95},
      {title: 'Data Package (1TB)', quantity: 0, price: 719.95},
      {title: 'Consulting (per hr.)', quantity: 0, price: 75.00}
    ];

    };
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend making a `grandTotal` function on your `$scope` and then binding that, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XMTQC/

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="CartController">
    Grand Total: <span>{{grandTotal()}}</span>
    <br/>
    Grand Total: <span ng-bind="grandTotal()"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.grandTotal = function () {
    return $scope.items.reduce(function (p, c) {
        return p.price || p + c.price;
    });
};
```

You can also use interpolation (instead of `ngBind`) as indicated in the first span.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but I need that grand total returns an object like: { baseTotal: 200.00, vat22: 44.00, total: 244.00 }  
  
And then print it like this:  
  
Base: {{grandTotal().baseTotal}}<br />  
VAT 22%: {{grandTotal().vat22}}<br />  
Total: {{grandTotal().total}}<br />  
  
But, doing so, it seems that the function would be called more at least 3 times!   
Isn't there a way to fetch the grandTotal() result into an intermediate value?  
  
Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about those 3 calls... they should be cheap and you shouldn't notice any slowdown.  Alternatively, you could change `grandTotal()` to write three values to scope (`$scope.baseTotal=X; $scope.vat22=Y; $scope.total=Z;`) and then call use `$watch` or `$watchCollection`  to monitor for changes in your items array and call `grandTotal()` when the collection changes.